# if statement display content even though no data

Tags: custom-field

I am trying to figure out why this page is showing content when the criteria isn´t being met.

I am using this code, so if there is a website in the custom meta box if will display the DIV with the a href in it:

```
<?php $infos = get_post_custom_values('_url'); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?></br class="clear">
<?php if ( $infos ) { ?>
  <div class="color-buttons color-button-blue website"><a href="http://<?php echo $infos[0]; ?>" target="_blank">Website →</a></div>
<?php } // endif ?>
```

If you look here: hhttp://globalicn.com/preview/regions/europe/#southern-europe the bottom Portugal link has no website, but the website link is there and shows `http:///`

If I delete the tag associated with this post, then the website link doesn´t display, which is correct. So when I add the tag Souther-Europe it somehow still adds the link.

Full code: http://pastebin.com/8taYL6Da

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like the return value of `get_post_custom_values()' is well defined in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_values). My guess is that as long as you have a costume field called '_url' set in any of your posts the result will be an empty array, and only if you don't have it in any post it will return null.

You probably better replace your check to

```
if (!empty($infos))
```

Comment: I always lean toward `!empty(...)` for this reason.